# Использование Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Пробую использовать lazy loading entityframework. Смотрю примеры с метанита. Но что то не получается. Там есть пример для связи 1 ко многим. Вот мой код:
Класс игрок:

```
class Player
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public int? TeamId { get; set; }
        public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
    }
```

Класс команда:

```
class Team
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Coach { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
        public Team()
        {
            Players = new List<Player>();
        }
    }
```

Контекст данных:

```
class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context()
            :base("MyConnect")
        { }

        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    }
```

И сам код в кнопке формы:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Context db = new Context())
            {
                var players = db.Players.ToList();
                foreach (var p in players)
                    Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name} - {p.Team.Name}");

                var teams = db.Teams.ToList();
                foreach (var t in teams)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{t.Name}");
                    foreach (var p in t.Players)
                        Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name}");
                }
            }
        }
```

Так же взятый с метанита.
Там утверждается что если свойства с модификаторами public и virtual то lazy loading будет работать без инклюдов и лодов. Но у меня вот этот код выпадает в ошибку как только доходит до строчки с `p.Team.Name` Так как у игрока не подтягивается коллекция команда. Но если я напишу `db.Teams.Load();` тогда всё заработает. Но по моему должно работать и так? Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём проблема? Может я что то не так делаю, уже всю голову сломал.

Comment: net-core? если да то там лейзи не поддерживается, вернее еще пока не поддерживается

Comment: @Сергей, нет не net.core обычный windows forms

Comment: У вас `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` в коде, да?

Comment: @AK вообще не писал эту строчку, просто на метаните не указано про это нечего. Коллега у себя дома делал точно так же как я, правда на wpf приложении и не писал этой строки и всё работало.

Comment: @AK да и даже сейчас вот пытаюсь написать эту строчку, у меня в this. нет Configuration. Возможно ещё что то нужно подключить, не подскажите? И снова же вопрос как без этой строчки сделать что бы всё работало

Comment: @AK пробежался по коду, нашёл что это включается в контексте, в отладке во время выполнения кода проверил значение, да оно в тру, но явно я эту строчку не писал.

Comment: @AK разница с метанитом наверное только в том что я явно добавил файл базы данных .mdf к проекту. А там этого не делают, но по моему это не помеха, при том что я свойство имеет нужное значение и как я выше упомянул, что если дописать в ручную load то всё сработает.

Comment: Вы не выполнили условие для lazy load: у вас классы не имеют модификатора public.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Классы в c# по умолчанию имеют модификатор internal, поэтому если вы пишете:

```
class Team {}
```

то ваш класс не public.

> Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in
>   other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can
>   be either public or internal. Internal is the default if no access
>   modifier is specified.

А именно это [влияет](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.2.php) на lazy load:

> При использовании ленивой загрузки надо иметь в виду некоторые моменты
>   при объявлении классов. Так, классы, использующие ленивую загрузку
>   должны быть публичными, а их свойства должны иметь модификаторы public
>   и virtual.

Пример на метаинте - с public.

Comment: Стоит один раз просидеть за отладкой несколько часов - сразу запоминаешь ;)

Comment: AK спасибо большое, работает, а скажите пожалуйста, я в этом пример попробовал убрать .ToList, что бы в переменной был тип iqueryable. Тогда уже команды как будто нет, в чём разница? `var players = db.Players` Вот так вот я сделал.

Comment: @Андрей Не уверен, что до конца понял, что вы хотите спросить, но это явно отдельный вопрос ;) Задавайте новый, а в этот ставьте галку, если заработало.

Comment: AK, да спасибо большое, всё работает.