# Как использовать колекции в Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

С помощью EntityFramework DataBaseFirst создались классы :

```
public partial class ExpSections
{
    public ExpSections()
    {
        ExpRemarks = new HashSet<ExpRemarks>();
    }
    public int ExpSectionId { get; set; }
    public int ExpMainId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ExpertName { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    public ExpMains ExpMain { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ExpRemarks> ExpRemarks { get; set; }
}

public partial class ExpRemarks
    {
        public int ExpRemarkId { get; set; }
        public int ExpSectionId { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public string Check { get; set; }

        public ExpSections ExpSection { get; set; }
    }
```

`ExpSections` связан один ко многим c `ExpRemarks`
Я так понимаю коллекция внутри класса `ExpSections` нужна для вывода связанных данных?
Как ей воспользоваться, к примеру есть метод:

```
public IActionResult Method(int id)
{
     ExpSections expSections = _bd.ExpSections.SingleOrDefault(m=>m.ExpSectionId == id);
```

А как получить связанные данные из класса ExpRemarks, если я пишу так:

```
Console.WriteLine(expSection.ExpRemark.Count());
```

Результат 0 записей, а в БД записи есть.

Comment: Почитайте про метод `Include`

Comment: В вопросе стоит упомянуть, у вас EF core 2.1 или ниже - есть разница.

Comment: @AK EntityFramework 2.0 , но есть возможность обновиться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В EF Core нет lazy loading (надо бы уточнить, не появилось ли в 2.1), поэтому у вас связанные данные не подгружаются автоматом.

Указывайте явно при загрузке, какие связанные данные вам понадобятся:

```
_bd.ExpSections.Include(x => x.ExpRemarks)
               .SingleOrDefault(m=>m.ExpSectionId == id);
```

[Тут](http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/news-2018-05-31-dot-net-core-2-1-and-frends-released) тёзка подсказывает, что в core 2.1 наконец впилили поддержку lazy loading так что если у вас есть возможность обновиться и включить lazy loading - то можете использовать как альтернативу.

Я правда люблю контролировать, что и когда грузится, это же лишние накладные расходы на базу и сеть, поэтому предпочитаю держать lazyloading отключенным.

Как включить lazy loading в 2.1 [см. в доках](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading), вкратце:

> The simplest way to use lazy-loading is by installing the
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies package and enabling it with a
>   call to `UseLazyLoadingProxies`

И, кстати, обращаю ваше внимание, что для поддержки lazy loading [свойства 
должны быть virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8542864/5752652):

```
public virtual ICollection<ExpRemarks> ExpRemarks { get; set; }
```

См. также:

- [Загрузка связанных данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/querying/related-data)
- [Entity Framework Core - Lazy Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40122162/5752652)

Answer (score 3):

Есть большая [таблица сравнения возможностей](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features), где показано, что "умеет" EF Core и, что важно, с какой версии - если умеет.

Многие, кто имеет опыт работы с EF6, очень часто забывают, что EF Core весьма сильно отличается от EF6, и, как следствие, получается такие ситуации.

Как верно подсказал @Андрей-NOP, Include может тут помочь.
Но, с версии 2.1 EF Core его можно больше не использовать, т.к. был реализован Lazy Loading.

Comment: Всё верно, только пара ремарок. Во-первых, в 2.1 нужно явно включать lazy loading (в ef6 помнится был включен автоматом). Во-вторых, не все условия для lazy loading выполнены (см. в моём ответе про virtual), а как показывает практика дело бывает в таких "мелочах", которые кажутся неважными ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/808865/213987)) и можно долго недоумевать, почему не работает. Но в целом - согласен, апвоут.

Comment: Да нет, ничего там явно не надо было. Я буквально полчаса назад проверял на тестовом проекте, фактически состоящем из сгенерированного кода. И про EF там просто регистрация в контейнере, и все.

Если есть пример с этим - буду благодарен, не хотелось бы "стрельнуть в ногу".

Comment: @AK, прочитал доку, не видел, оказывается. Надо протестировать, благодарю за подсказку!