# Обнуление ссылок после взятия из БД Entity Framework

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, null, entity-framework-6

Есть DataContext:

```
public class MyDataModel : DbContext
    {
        public MyDataModel()
            : base("name=MyDataModel")
        {
        }

        static MyDataModel()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MyContextInializer());
        }

        public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    }
```

В инициализаторе у меня такой код:

```
class MyContextInializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDataModel>
{ // при каждом запуске база удаляется и создается, используя Seed(..).
    protected override void Seed(MyDataModel context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);
        var c1 = new Company { Name = "Samsung"};
        var c2 = new Company { Name = "Microsoft"};
        context.Companies.AddRange(new List<Company>{c1,c2 });
        var phones = new List<Phone>
        {
            new Phone("Samsung Galaxy S5", 20000, c1),
            new Phone("Nokia S1243", 200000, c1),
            new Phone("Nokia 930", 10000, c2),
            new Phone("Nokia 890", 8900, c2)

        };
        context.Phones.AddRange(phones);

        context.SaveChanges();
        var a = context.Phones.ToListAsync().Result; // a[0].Company!=null
    }
}
```

a - это `List<Phone>`. `a[0].Company`!=`null`. Однако в любом другом месте поле Company почему-то равно null. Почему?
Любое другое место:

```
using (var db = new MyDataModel())
        {
            var phonesList = db.Phones.ToList(); // phonesList[0].Company is null.
        }
```

Код `Phone`:

```
public class Phone
{
    public Phone()
    {

    }
    public Phone(string name, int price, Company company)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
        Company = company;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Вообще-то могли бы привести код ваших классов Company и Phone - но судя по всему - просто не подключаете через `.Include()` связанные сущности и не работает Lazy Loading. например, [поэтому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/808899/213987).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что ж, я просто не загружал `Company`.
А в инициализаторе поле `Company` было не `null` из-за кэша, т.е. обращения к самой БД не происходило.
Сейчас я знаю два подхода, которые решили мою проблему:
Подход с использованием Include (называется Eager loading):

```
var phonesList = db.Phones.Include(nameof(Phone.Company));
// nameof можно заменить на строку, получится db.Phones.Include("Company"); Получается читабельнее.
// альтернатива: var phonesList = db.Phones.Include(p=>p.Company)); // Для этого нужно подключить using System.Data.Entity;
```

Подход с virtual navigation property (называется Lazy loading:)

```
//Если кратко, то просто надо сделать нужное свойство virtual, и тогда EF будет подгружать нужную Company, когда это нужно.
public class Phone
{
    public Phone()
    {

    }
    public Phone(string name, int price, Company company)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
        Company = company;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

}
```

Отличия этих подходов: [Отложенная загрузка данных](https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level3/3_4.php)

MSDN: [Loading Related Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx)

Comment: необязательно делать nameof, имхо лучше лямбдочкой: 
`db.Phones.Include(p => p.Company));`

Comment: @SultanovShamil, у меня почему-то недоступны методы лямбд. Только string: "can't convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: `using System.Data.Entity;` если используете EF4,3 и выше

Comment: @SultanovShamil спасибо, дополню ответ.