# ошибка: недоступен из-за уровня защиты, entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

ShowOrders выдаёт ошибку :'ShowOrders.ShowOrders(string)' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122) [Project_Geolab]

```
else if("R" == command)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Name");
                var email = Console.ReadLine();

                new ShowOrders(email).Show();
            }


public class ShowOrders 
{
    private readonly string email;

    ShowOrders(string email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        using(Technic context = new Technic())
        {
            var findedRecords = context.Customers.Where(r => r.Email == this.email).ToList();
            if(findedRecords.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach(var item in findedRecords)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Id: {item.Id} Name: {item.Name} Age: {item.Age}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public` дописать?

Comment: `public ShowOrders(string email)`

Comment: что? не понял .

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Использование Lazy Loading](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/808865/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-lazy-loading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо Вы создаёте класс из другой сборки. По умолчанию (если не указан модификатор доступа) у члена класса будет область видимости `internal`.

Сделайте `public`.

```
public class ShowOrders 
{
    private readonly string email;

    public ShowOrders(string email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }
. . .
```